# React Hook Form and Material ui component-inputRef not working-A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

When i try to use React hook form and material ui component i received the following error

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info.

When i tried to use inputRef it is still not working.

```
<TextField
    autoFocus
    margin="dense"
    id="name"
    label="Name"
    type="text"
    fullWidth
    inputRef={register}
/>
{ <Controller
    as={TextField}
    name='test'
    control={control}
    placeholder='test'
>}
```

Comment: Take a look at this section: https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller there is a codesandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-qsd8r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the value that will resolve your uncontrolled input problem.

```
value={ this.state.value || "" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the controller for a simple `TextInput` field. You should get rid of it and see if your warning dissappear.